# xPages don't work after design update

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

1. Load any xPage
2. Refresh db design
3. Reload the xPage by either F5 or Ctrl+F5.

then almost all functions stop working without any errors. E.g. nothing happen if you click buttons or menu items. After restarting web browser some functions come back but some still doesn't work. After cleaning browser's cache almost 90% UI start working but some still need to reload the page few times. Is there any xPage app properties or Domino properties to adjust to fix that problem and make xPage app work smooth even after design refresh

Comment: Did you try to manually clean and build the application after the design refresh? This should happen automatically if you have checked "Refresh entire application when design changes" in the Xsp Properties of your database (Application Configuration > Xsp Properties). However, I suggest you try it manually before searching for other errors...

Comment: Please clarify server version and client version refreshing design, including the Fix Pack installed. This may be relevant if refreshing is done via an 8.5.3 client.

Comment: I do replace design several times daily, never any issues on webpage after F5, using 9.0.1

Comment: Domino Release 8.5.3FP6HF2326 (Linux 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP), Notes Client Release 8.5.3FP6 SHF577, and of course I always clean the project before refresh

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstandings: With "clean and build the application after the design refresh" I was refering to the application that has been refreshed, not the application that has been used for the refresh (Master template).

Comment: OK.. Usually I refresh my template (ntf) where I do changes .. Then I refresh main nsf db from that template

Comment: Have you tried "restart task http" on the server console?

Comment: we did try but I don't think it's something related to Domino..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Design Refresh didn't reload custom Java classes when refreshing with 8.5.3 FP1. This was fixed, I believe, in FP2. But that doesn't sound like it's causing the problem here.

Design Refresh will not reload jar files. That requires issuing "restart task http" to the console. ("tell http restart" doesn't properly reload everything XPages needs.)

If your application is using a Single Copy XPage Design to hold its XPages design, that too will not update until you issue "restart task http" to the server. The design seems to be cached by the server for better performance,  but refreshing the design of the SCXD database doesn't reload that design. It's unclear if that's your scenario here.

XPiNC may also not update immediately, but I've not tried that. The runtime there is basically in the Notes Client itself, so I could understand that it would not update.

Otherwise, I would echo Thomas's experience, I've not seen any other issues (and my applications heavily use Java). I haven't needed to clean the application following a design refresh. Existing browser sessions will have problems with partial refresh calls, I would expect that. But a refresh of the page make all functionality work.

There are two scenarios I would expect to have problems.

The first is if you are storing anything in sessionScope or applicationScope variables that are required by your application, but your code only loads those on a specific page. If you refresh the design, the scopes will get dumped and so not reloaded until you go to the specific page. Typically I put such initialisation code on my layout custom control, so a page reload will always initialise it if it's dumped by a design refresh.

The second is if another user accesses the application and has Build Automatically switched on, which could result in the application being rebuilt without you realising it. It doesn't sound like this is happening for you though.