# Where should properties files be stored in an XPages application?

Tags: java, xpages

I have an Xpage application that uses the `docx4j-ImportXHTML` library.  The jar file is stored on the server in the *jvm/lib/ext* folder.  There is a properties file that comes with it that I want to use.  The documentation says to use it, add it to the class path.

I've tried adding it to the build path, tried putting it in the same folder as the jar, but neither of these works.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting the file in the Code/Java folder in the nsf

Comment: Thanks @PerHenrikLausten  I tried that.  In the end, a server restart seemed to do the trick whilst leaving the properties file in the lib/ext folder.

Comment: I will suggest that you add your solution as an answer and close the question

Answer (score 0):

In the end, a server restart seemed to do the trick whilst leaving the properties file in the lib/ext folder

Comment: Probably "restart task http" would be sufficient.

Comment: What's probably also relevant here is whether you'd initially tried the application with the jar file but the properties in the wrong place. I believe "restart task http" is required to reload jar files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728957/xpages-dont-work-after-design-update. So if you'd got the properties files in the right place first time, it might have been fine; if you didn't, it might have needed an http restart for every change you made. Similarly, I'm not sure what happens if you make a change to the properties file. Maybe something for someone to investigate and blog about.